# Haskell leftmost deepest node of tree

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, nested, nested-lists

Suppose I have a binary tree structure defined as

```hs
data IntTree = Empty | Node Int IntTree IntTree
```

and the tree

```hs
Node 0 (Node 1 Empty Empty)(Node 2 (Node 3 Empty Empty)(Node 4 Empty Empty))
```

How can I extract the leftmost deepest node (ie `Node 3 Empty Empty`)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem just updated the question using a Tree structure instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make use of recursion and define a helper function that returns the depth of the node, then for each innode, you select the deepest child. Such function thus looks like:

```
leftmostDeep : IntTree -> IntTree
leftmostDeep = fst . go
    where go n@(Node _ Empty Empty) = (n, 0)
          go n@(Node _ Empty r) = let (nr, dr) = go r in (nr, dr+1)
          go n@(Node _ l Empty) = let (nl, dl) = go l in (nl, dl+1)
          go (Node l r) = …
              where (na, da) = go l
              where (nb, db) = go r
```

where `…` is left as an exercise. This should determine which item is the deepest, and as tiebreaker, return the left subtree. You should also increment the depth of that node with one.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Node 0 (Node 1 Empty Empty)(Node 2 (Node 3 Empty Empty)(Node 4 Empty Empty))]
[        Node 1 Empty Empty, Node 2 (Node 3 Empty Empty)(Node 4 Empty Empty) ]
[               Empty,Empty,         Node 3 Empty Empty, Node 4 Empty Empty  ]
[                                           Empty,Empty,        Empty,Empty  ]
[                                                                            ]
```

suggests

```
deepest :: IntTree -> [Int]
deepest  =  pure  >>>  iterate (>>= g)  >>>  takeWhile (not . null) 
                  >>>  reverse  >>>  drop 1  >>>  take 1
                  >>>  (>>= \ xs -> [i | Node i _ _ <- xs])
  where
  g (Node _ lt rt) = [lt, rt]
  g Empty = []
```

and then we get

```
> deepest $ Node 0 (Node 1 Empty Empty)
                   (Node 2 (Node 3 Empty Empty) (Node 4 Empty Empty))
[3,4]
```

so all that's left is to `take 1` from that, if you want to.